# StartUpload method REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

I've been looking to use the following in the REST API
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations#FileresourceCreateorupdateafile

Has anyone been able to use this successfully? When I first used the Startupload method it says the file does not exist, I guess it wouldn't as I'm trying to upload the file anyway. So as a test I created a file through the web UI. When I go to run it again this is the response I get:

> {"error":{"code":"-1, System.NotImplementedException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The method or operation is not implemented."}}}

It says its only available in office 365

> "This method is currently available only on Office 365."

So I should be able to use it?

I'm trying to upload a file which is over 300mb, using the below uploads the file but I don't get any response returned ie request.GetResponse() it just hangs.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FileCollectionAdd

In a nut shell I want to be able to upload large files.

I've tried the below:
http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/uploading-large-documents-into.html

The response hangs on files over 300mb

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you try with a small file, is it getting uploaded?

Comment: Yes, I can upload the 327mb file. I just cant get a response. WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); it just hangs

Answer (score 0):

FYI I know this question is 6 years old, but I was able to get it to work.

This link has some good examples, before you can use start upload you need to create a empty file.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery